# why react-native cannot detect my props

Tags: android, react-native

i give to props to another component
example

```
<LoadImage image={images} />
```

on component LoadImage

in method render i give console.log()

```
render(){
 console.log(this.props.image,'&', this.props.image.originHeight)
}
```

why debug mode on this.props.image give me description object with hasproperty originHeight on image.
but in this.props.image.originHeight give result undefined?

[image]

Comment: ignore that, sometime happens.

Comment: but i cannot give height (num) for my image